# How to prove that a surface area is infinite and volume finite?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that the surface area of z = f(x,y) is infinite and the volume inside this surface is $\pi$, while

$$z = \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, z > 1 $$

I know this problem has something to do with Gabriel's horn and integration but I can't wrap my head around how to solve this.

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Comment: I would have thought it'd be easy to show infinite surface area!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of the horn at $z$ is $$r=\frac 1z.$$

(Because $z=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac1r.$)

Take a look at the horn:

[image]

So the surface element at $z$ is $$2\pi\times r \times\Delta z=2\pi\times \frac1z \times\Delta z$$

and the volume element is

$$\pi \Delta z \frac 1{z^2}.$$

The surface is then

$$A=2\pi\int_0^{\infty}\frac 1z \ dz=\infty$$

and the volume is

$$V=\pi\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1{z^2} \ dz=\pi(-1)\left[\frac 1z\right]_1^{\infty}=\pi.$$